# Manually delete workflows from YouTrack server

Tags: workflow, youtrack

For whatever range of poor reasons...a user schedule workflow has been uploaded to our YouTrack server instance that now automatically generates seemingly hundreds of new issues a minute.

As you might imagine, the web server is totally unresponsive, meaning that we cannot disable or detach the workflow from the project. The workflow editor's attempts to remove the workflow fail with connection timeouts.

How can the workflow be disabled without accessing the usual admin pages? Is there a workflow file somewhere in the server's directory that can be deleted (I can't find one) while the service is stopped? Is there a "run in safe-mode" option for YouTrack?

We're running YouTrack 5 fwiw.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YouTrack 6.0 we've implemented special Java start parameter (-Djetbrains.youtrack.workflow.detachModified=true), it will work starting from next bug fix release. 
This option will detach all the workflows from all the projects on start, except the unmodified supplied ones. 
Please, consider https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-27785, the Fix version of this issue will be changes as soon as we release next bug fix.

Comment: This flag does not exist in recent versions of YouTrack. If you experience a workflow problem that prevents YouTack from starting, your only option is to restore from backup.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows are stored inside YT db, so the best variant for you is to contact YT support. It'll be able to modify the db.